# VirtualBox window doesn’t scale up to full-screen

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions

Sometimes my VirtualBox doesn’t scale up to full-screen and bloats to a very unpleasant stretched mode when I try to maximize the window it.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens when the Graphics controller configured in VirtualBox Display settings isn’t supported. 
PS : Guest Extensions needs to be installed for this option to work properly. So install them from VirtualBox website (as per Host OS you have installed VirtualBox upon).

To fix this issue, stop the instance of VirtualBox Guest OS you wish to up-scale to full-screen.

Graphics Controller ==> VBoxSVGA

[See settings at link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJUK0.png)

If this post was helpful for you, kindly up-vote the answer and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I turn off "3D Acceleration" and only after that success switch to full screen mode

Comment: I do not get the screen entirely to "full screen", since the rest of the screen is just black and I got a smaller box wherein I have the vm screen.